# How can I see the value of RewriteRule or RewriteCond server variables?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For example, if I want to see what value is in some variable in php I do this:

```
$foo = 'This is a variable foo';

var_dump($foo);  // string(22) "This is a variable foo"
echo $foo;       // This is a variable foo
print_r $foo;    // This is a variable foo
```

But when I write some `mod_rewrite` rules, for now I can only guess what value comes to the RewriteRule and what it becomes after rewriting `($0)`:

```
<Directory /public>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</Directory>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]   // what is %{REQUEST_FILENAME}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $0 [NC, L]             // what is ^(.+)$, and what is $0?
```

Is there any way to print or somehow to see what value I get after each line? For example, I'd like to see what comes in `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $0 [NC, L]`, what is in `^(.+)$` and what is then in `$0`.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't the way you ask.

The error log is a good help. Set LogLevel to debug, like this:  `LogLevel debug` in the `httpd.conf` file.

If using Firefox, you can try [livehttpheaders](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/), for example, to watch the headers and other relevant information. There are equivalent extensions for other browsers.

Needless to say, a php script at the mapped address with `echo var_dump($_SERVER);` or similar statement, will display a complete information of the result.