# is there a way to see how a mod-rewrite acts in real-time?

Tags: debugging, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-redirect

I had a mod-rewrite rule that worked just fine for a few months:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

(this is located in site/folder).

This would redirect people from site/folder/something to site/folder/index.php?q=something, leaving the url nice and pretty.

Now, suddenly, while nobody touches the .htaccess file nor the code of the relevant pages, it has stopped working. While the urls stays the same as before, the content of the page is of site/index.php instead of (site/folder/index.php?q=something).

How can I debug this, what tools will allow me to follow the flow of the redirection rule?

Comment: Check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927208/how-can-i-see-the-value-of-rewriterule-or-rewritecond-server-variables), might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the server or vhost config, you can add these lines:

```
        RewriteLog /tmp/rewrite.log
        RewriteLogLevel 5
```

Then you can look at the output written to `/tmp/rewrite.log` (or wherever of your choosing) to see what mod_rewrite is doing in real-time. If you don't see any output, then the rules you have aren't being applied at all (possibly the override has changed or mod_rewrite isn't loaded?).